# What's the use of StackFrame.GetNativeOffset()?

Tags: .net, reflection, il

The `StackFrame` class has the `GetILOffset` and `GetNativeOffset` methods. I know what they're for. But I cannot imagine any use for the native offset. It's depending on the JIT and can be different every time the code is executed. Also since it's temporarily compiled on the executing machine, it cannot be analysed later by the developer.

Are there any situations where this native offset can tell anything that the IL offset (alone) cannot?

Comment: It is obscure, might be useful to annotate a minidump.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Are there any situations where this native offset can tell anything that the IL offset (alone) cannot?*

The `GetNativeOffset` method returns the offset to native just-in-time code in memory. `GetILOffset` method returns the offset for the MSIL code in memory.

So yes, basically it always does since they both point to a different offset, but on the other hand, no, as (like you said) it can be changed at any time.

I've seen more people using `GetILOffset` then `GetNativeOffset`, to be honest, the only time I have seen `GetNativeOffset` was being used was actually inside the .NET framework itself.